# How to get the Spark scala correlation output as a dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to calculate correlation for all columns in a Spark dataframe using the below code.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Matrix, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.ml.stat.Correlation
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("SparkCorrelation")
  .master("local[*]")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (0.1, 0.3, 0.5),
  (0.2, 0.4, 0.6),
).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3")

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("c1", "c2", "c3"))
  .setOutputCol("vectors")

val transformed = assembler.transform(df)

val corr = Correlation.corr(transformed, "vectors","pearson")

corr.show(100,false)
```

My output comes out as a dataframe with one column.

| pearson(vectors) |
| --- |
| 1.0 1.0000000000000002 0.9999999999999998 \n1.0000000000000002 1.0 1.0000000000000002 \n0.9999999999999998 1.0000000000000002 1.0 |

but I want my output in the following format. Can somebody please help?

| Column | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | 1 | 0.97 | 0.92 |
| c2 | 0.97 | 1 | 0.94 |
| c3 | 0.92 | 0.94 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Best you can do is this, but without cols:

```
val corr = Correlation.corr(transformed, "vectors", "pearson").head
println(s"Pearson correlation matrix:\n $corr")
```

Comment: Is there a way to add columns after generating the above dataframe?

Comment: I think not. The idea is that visual sighting should be enough as normally cardinality of cols c is low. Other tools do that standardly.

Comment: The above dataframe was just an example. my original datasets will have 300 cols or more. So, I would be needing the output as in the desired dataframe format I mentioned earlier. Then, I will using the dataframe for further downstream processing.

Comment: All things can be done but I have  never seen that.